# how do I limit the contents of my dropdown by the associated user_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view, ruby-on-rails-4

in my rails view I have a form with a dropdown that looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@appointment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.association :client, label_method: lambda { |c| "#{c.first_name} #{c.last_name}" } %>
    <%= f.input :occured_on %>
    <%= f.input :start %>
    <%= f.input :end %>
    <%= f.input :copay_received %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I would like to limit the contents of the dropdown to only the clients associated with current_user.id.

How do I accomplish this?

Let me know if you need to see my controller or something else but it does nothing fancy. I bet you can guess it's contents.

Comment: you can restrict by using collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the collection argument:

```
<%= f.association :client, label_method: lambda { |c| "#{c.first_name} #{c.last_name}" }, collection: Client.where(user_id: current_user.id) %>
```

Alternative:

```
# this implies you have declared: user has_many :clients
<%= f.association :client, collection: current_user.clients, label_method: lambda{|c| "..."} %>
```

Comment: sweet! +1 for the less verbose alternative :-)